# Как сделать прозрачный текст?

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация

Мне нужно чтобы была кнопка, в которой текст был как фон (т.е. просто "дырявил блок")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может пример приведите...

Comment: хорошо, приведу

Comment: css - нельзя сделать(не считая background-clip, который еще не поддерживается почти никем емнип). SVG - можно

Comment: Ну, подскажите.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Две SVG кнопки с прозрачным текстом.**

Анимация начинается при наведении курсора на цветные полоски слева. 
Прозрачный текст кнопок реализован при помощи SVG маски.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ8Hg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
    <defs>
      <mask id="hole">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="200" fill="white"/>
        <text x="57" y="110" font-size="40"  fill="black"> Button- </text> 
      </mask> 
      <mask id="hole1">
        <rect x="0" y="250" width="400" height="200" fill="white"/>
        <text x="57" y="310" font-size="40" fill="black"> Button+ </text> 
      </mask>   
    </defs>
    <rect id="green" x="-175" y="50" rx="25" ry="25" width="200" height="100" fill="yellowgreen" mask="url(#hole)">
      <animate attributeName="x" from="-175" to="25" begin="green.mouseover" dur="1.5s" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>
    </rect> 
    <rect id="dodger" x="-175" y="250" rx="25" ry="25" width="200" height="100" fill="dodgerblue" mask="url(#hole1)">
      <animate attributeName="x" from="-175" to="25" begin="dodger.mouseover" dur="1.5s" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

```css
div#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5807/zzots.6/0_5e7c3_42723e72_XXL.jpg);
}

div#button {
  background: white;      
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 73px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 72px;
}

div#button span { 
     background: url(http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5807/zzots.6/0_5e7c3_42723e72_XXL.jpg) -73px -160px no-repeat;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="button">
    <span>КНОПКА</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Замечу, что тут два фона: один основной и один - у текста кнопки.

Важно в `background` с текстом поставить тот же фон, на котором кнопка и находится и сместить её на такое количество пикселей, на котором кнопка смещена относительно основного фона

---

По поводу поддержки браузерами - не могу подсказать, какие версии поддерживают. Самые последние Chrome/FF/Edge - точно работают

Поэтому, как мне кажется, лучше такое пока изображать в SVG

Comment: `-webkit-background-clip` в FF и Edge? <s>Что-то не думаю.</s> UPDATE: Действительно работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy тебя только у `background-clip`  это  смутило? )) теперь стоит задать вопрос на ruSO - какого чёрта это работает ;-)

Comment: Просто все растаскивают вебкитовский префикс. Первая была Опера 12 :)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну опера-то понятно. они давно сдались) но чтоб сам MS!!! хых

Comment: Уже IE11 умел градиенты с префиксом вебкита

Comment: Кстати, в IE11 не работает - получается прямоугольник фона с чёрным текстом :)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну так я и написал, что Edge :)

Comment: Ну так да - там работает - это я уже подтвердил :)

Answer (score 4):

Еще один вариант, но есть проблема с поддержкой браузерами.
**mix-blend-mode** на данный момент не работает в в ie/edge и частично в Safari

```css
h1{
    background:  black;
    color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```