# паралакс фона в тексте

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Нужно сделать на странице надпись с фоновым изображением. Также нужно применить для фона паралакс эффект. Как можно реализовать такое, если можно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прозрачный текст кнопок при помощи SVG маски.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать это с помощью CSS, но лучше использовать SVG.

Почитай тут: [Как сделать прозрачный текст?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663012/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82)

Паралакс легко можно сделать при помощи Jquery. Например: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/